# vaadin7 passwordfield inputprompt mask text with asterisks

Tags: vaadin7

Vaadin7 (7.4.0) password field mask inputprompt text with asterisks which is not the intended behavior. Have anyone got workaround to fix this and display the text on password field?

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin seems to set input prompt as value of the field for browser compatibility reason. I think html5 [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) would be better, but it is not supported by all browsers that are supported by vaadin. 
If you know that your users are not using unsupported browsers you could use an extension described [here](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/1959404).

Btw. There are already tickets in the bug tracker:

- [Vaadin 7](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/9562)
- [Vaadin 6](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/2856)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on raffael's answer this is what I used in Vaadin 7:

```
PasswordField password = new PasswordField();
password.setID("PasswordID");
Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("document.getElementById('PasswordID').placeholder = 'Password';");
```

If you try to use the setInputPrompt() function it overrides the placeholder (since it's treated as the field's value).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use DOM add on vaadin 7

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/dom

Dom dom = new Dom(this.passwordField);

dom.setAttribute("placeholder", "Password");